Missing one method from stack trace
I have an ASP .NET Core 3.1 web app.
I make a request from the client and the stack trace is:
MethodFromController()
MethodFromRepository()
SaveChangesAsync() - overridden from EF Core 3.1
Inside SaveChangesAsync(), I tried getting the stack trace like this:
var _1 = Environment.StackTrace;
var _2 = new StackTrace().ToString();
var _3 = new StackTrace().GetFrames();

For _1 and _2 the stack trace contains only the last 2 methods: MethodFromRepository(), SaveChangesAsync(). For _3, I don't get anything from the above (only methods which are not from my project/namespace).
I'm trying to get the all the 3 methods (including MethodFromController()), but can't figure out how I could do it. It's also interesting that for SaveChanges(), all 3 variables contain the methods mentioned above.
It's worth noting that MethodFromController() lies inside a project, while the other 2 lie inside another project (2 projects in total).
LATER EDIT
What I'm trying to achieve is to have the stack trace inserted for any add/update/delete operation on any table of my database. I overrode SaveChanges() & SaveChangesAsync() and tried getting the stack trace there. This way, I know where to look if something unexpected/bad happens.

Does the stack trace contain the missing method in Debug build? If so, the culprit can be the JIT inlining that may improve the performance in Release build. If you forcibly want to prevent that from happening apply the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] attribute on the MethodForController method. And please note that default inlining behavior can change from version to version.

@GyörgyKőszeg It didn't work, but even if it did, I would have to add that attribute on a lot of methods. Isn't there another way?
